# Why does Angular Controller need "$scope"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I have normally learned  that function implementation can have any name for function arguments as long as it is supplied in the right order. This makes the function abstracted from the outside world and the local names have no effect on the output . Implementer has all the rights for local variables. However in Angular JS, it seems to counter intuitive to have something like:

```
function Controller($scope)
{
    $scope.name = "Something";
}
```

If I put "bar" there instead "$scope" I get an error. This is not the normal function that we are used to . I believe it something to do with DI, but can anyone explain this concept ? I find it  hard to call this a "function" because it is dependent on the outside world - especially the argument name .

If DI is the real reason , can any one let me know how does it get invoked ? Normally I can think of DI doing good when I want to mock an object for test case. In this case what role does DI play ?

In the normal scenarios of DI that I have come across , the argument that gets passed, does a service for the function like say foo displayTime(clock) { clock.something } . Time is just a service for the the function . However here I find that , the $scope and the framework seems to do the magic with the function just being declarative way of expressing the logic .

Edit : Apparently JS minify breaks this functionality and we need to do like in [How do the function argument names in Angular.js objects connect to other objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949889/how-do-the-function-argument-names-in-angular-js-objects-connect-to-other-object?lq=1)

Comment: Angular actually evaluates the arguments (using Function.toString ) names and injects the right resource, this is one of the baffling things you learn when you get started with angular ! see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949889/how-do-the-function-argument-names-in-angular-js-objects-connect-to-other-object

Comment: "In normal scenarios of DI I have come across , the argument that gets passed does a service for the function"... This is also the case in Angular, scopes are however a little special... https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes which goes into details about scopes and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope which probably sticks more to how you should use them
But you may just as well inject your own clock service defined as: myApp.service('clock', ['otherDependency', function(od) { this.something = "Im a clock!"; }]);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to define a controller is like so:

```
myApp.controller("TestController", ['$scope', function(bar) {
   // now "bar" is actually the scope variable
}]);
```

The whole reason that angular works like this is because of the way it does dependency injection. Basically it looks for the dependancies (eg `$scope`) and it tries to inject them based on name of the variable. That means if you name `$scope` something different then it tries to inject that other item instead. `bar` isn't something that angular knows how to inject so you are going to get an `undefined` value instead of the `$scope` you were expecting.

My example above works because I used an array to separate out the names of the variables that are going to be injected from the variables themselves. Now you don't have to use the word `$scope` but you must keep the variables in the same order. The whole concept of DI is too complicated to explain in a short post so I recommend reading more about it on angular's site here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

**The Point of DI (in angular)**

In case you are wondering - why go to all this trouble? Why not just automatically inject `$scope` into the first variable that you have in the list? The answer is - flexibility & customization. With angular, you can define your services and factories, then inject them into your controllers. This gives you the power to define shared routines, objects or even custom controls and then use them across as many controllers as you want. Without DI - none of this would be possible. Again, these are pretty complicated concepts so I recommend starting with a leap of faith that "it works", learning about services, then later you can go back and read more about it. At that point I think DI should make a whole lot more sense!

Best of luck!

Comment: Interesting . So basically you mean the function is mean to be called by Angular and not outside world ? Its not purely a JS function ?

Comment: @Nishant You can call the function as you defined it from anything, but it obviously won't be doing you much good. 

Regardless, you should use the syntax drew_w provides here as it also means you can safely minify your code without breaking the functionality.

Comment: @Nishant It uses DI to inject variables, *but* it is still a pure javascript function. I recommend reading more about DI to understand what is going on here!

Comment: Yes I mean the DI has special purpose for Angular framework . Right I would check into DI concept .

Comment: @Nishant Angular uses it's injector ($injector) for most instantiations and calls to functions you defined in an angular application... The injector is an IoC container. DI it self doesn't do anything of all this as it just specifies a concept for providing an object/service with what it needs from the outside. The IoC container means you can automate the whole creation process. So you should probably also read a little up on IoC containers. In JavaScript we can't resolve things by "Type" or "Interface", so instead we use names.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks http://merrickchristensen.com/articles/javascript-dependency-injection.html is something I understood before asking this question . Its just how and where does it get applied kind of thing .

Comment: For a short awnser to you second question, where does this get invoked... This all depends. Controllers get's created by Angular OR other frameworks in relation to it. (When we are talking Angular controllers anyways). And you can attach them in many ways. The most simple way would be to use the ng-controller directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) and let's not go into directives here... Other places would be within defined routes using the ngRoute modules, or on views when using e.g. modules like: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing so it really depends.

Comment: I thought one of the main points of DI was to make the code easier to test.

Comment: @Adam That is also true. Basically any reason you can think of for separating the actual implementation details for a dependency from the use of that dependency is a reason to use DI. Substituting mock objects for real objects during testing is a certainly perfect example of this.